# Exception Handling in Pandas .apply() function

Tags: python, exception, pandas

If I have a DataFrame:

```
myDF = DataFrame(data=[[11,11],[22,'2A'],[33,33]], columns = ['A','B'])
```

Gives the following dataframe (Starting out on stackoverflow and don't have enough reputation for an image of the DataFrame)

```
   | A  | B  |

0  | 11 | 11 |

1  | 22 | 2A |

2  | 33 | 33 |
```

If i want to convert column B to int values and drop values that can't be converted I have to do:

```
def convertToInt(cell):
    try:
        return int(cell)
    except:
        return None
myDF['B'] = myDF['B'].apply(convertToInt)
```

If I only do:

> myDF['B'].apply(int)

the error obviously is:

> C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd
>   in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:42840)()
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2A'

Is there a way to add exception handling to myDF['B'].apply()

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

much better/faster to do:

```
In [1]: myDF = DataFrame(data=[[11,11],[22,'2A'],[33,33]], columns = ['A','B'])

In [2]: myDF.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[2]: 
    A   B
0  11  11
1  22 NaN
2  33  33

[3 rows x 2 columns]

In [3]: myDF.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
Out[3]: 
A      int64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

This is a vectorized method of doing just this. The `coerce` flag say to mark as `nan` anything that cannot be converted to numeric.

You can of course do this to a single column if you'd like.

Comment: Please note that `convert_objects()` is deprecated from Pandas 0.21.0

Answer (score 65):

I had the same question, but for a more general case where it was hard to tell if the function would generate an exception (i.e. you couldn't explicitly check this condition with something as straightforward as `isdigit`).

After thinking about it for a while, I came up with the solution of embedding the `try/except` syntax in a separate function. I'm posting a toy example in case it helps anyone.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a','a'], [1,2]]))

def augment(x):
    try:
        return int(x)+1
    except:
        return 'error:' + str(x)

x[0].apply(lambda x: augment(x))
```

Comment: I think this answers the question, whilst the accepted answer solves the problem in a different way.

Comment: I got an `unnecessary lambda` warning from Pylint for this, so I just used `x[0].apply(augment)` and it gets passed what it needs.

Answer (score 20):

A way to achieve that with `lambda`:

```
myDF['B'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if str(x).isdigit() else None)
```

For your input:

```
>>> myDF
    A   B
0  11  11
1  22  2A
2  33  33

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

```
>>> myDF['B'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if str(x).isdigit() else None)
0    11
1   NaN
2    33
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @RukTech: just want to clarify that the dtype is float64 b/c there is no integer version of NaN

Comment: Or use `'None'` instead of `None` in the else clause.

Comment: @Paul: It is float64, my main aim is to convert from object to numeric type. Good catch though

Comment: If I don't know what the error is, how could I handle the exception?