# Exception handling when using pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exception, apply

I can extract a substring from a pandas series using series.str.extract.

```
ds = pd.Series(['1A apple', '1B pear', '3C orange', 'grape'])
ds.str.extract('(\\d.{1}).*', expand=False)
```

What I tried initially was using apply function.

```
ds.apply(lambda x: re.search('(\\d.{1}).*', x).group(1))
```

I got error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

It seems that the search pattern does not apply to the fourth element `'grape'`. So it retuns a nonetype.  My question is how I can fix the apply function above to make it work? I'm curious about how to use the apply function to achieve the same task using str.extract.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception Handling in Pandas .apply() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847304/exception-handling-in-pandas-apply-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need a custom function to handle errors, simple as that. You can do that with a `try...except` block, or using an `if` statement to test the value of the match object returned by `re.search`.

```
def search(x):
    try:
        return re.search('(\\d.{1}).*', x).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        return np.nan
```

```
ds.apply(search)

0     1A
1     1B
2     3C
3    NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get cute with the `lambda` and use `if/else` to check if result of `re.search` is `None`.  Technically, I'm just evaluating the truthiness of the search result.  But `re.search` is supposed to evaluate to `True` if the pattern was found and `False` otherwise, so this should work.

```
ds.apply(
    lambda x: (
        lambda y: y.group(1) if y else np.nan
    )(re.search('(\\d.{1}).*', x))
)

0     1A
1     1B
2     3C
3    NaN
dtype: object
```

The less cute way to do the same thing

```
def search(x):
    s = re.search('(\\d.{1}).*', x)
    if s:
        return s.group(1)

ds.apply(search)

0      1A
1      1B
2      3C
3    None
dtype: object
```